# Verificar se item existe no array

Tags: php

Tenho este objeto.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [assessoria_id] => 1
    [id] => 3
    [nome] => wagner.fillio
    [cpf] => 00000000000
    [login] => wagner.fillios
    [ramal] => 123
    [pin] => 123
    [reset_senha] => 
    [sistema] => 
    [ativo] => 1
    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pessoa_id] => 3
                    [id] => 13
                    [email] => teste@teste.com
                    [observacao] => 
                    [preferencial] => 1
                    [ativo] => 1
                    [origem_dados_id] => 1
                    [crud] => R
                )

        )

    [unidade] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_empty_] => 
        )

    [view] => stdClass Object
        (
            [equipe] => 61 a 90
        )

)
```

E esta função:

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
    {
        print_r($dados);        
        $operador = [
            'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
            'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
            'ope_login'       => $dados->login,         
            //'ope_senha'       => $dados->senha,           
            'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
            'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
            'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
            'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
        ];

        $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

Preciso identificar se neste objeto, existe o item `$senha`. Posso fazer isto?

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
    {
        print_r($dados);        
        $operador = [
            'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
            'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
            'ope_login'       => $dados->login,

            if(in_array($dados->senha, $dados)
            {
                'ope_senha'  => $dados->senha,  
            }

            //'ope_senha'       => $dados->senha,           
            'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
            'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
            'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
            'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
        ];

        $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

Comment: Utilize [isset](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php)

Comment: Já tentei  e tenho isso: Message:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ']', sei que tenho que utilizar o if fora do array, assim teria que repetir o array $operador, tirando o item $senha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `isset`

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
{
    if (!isset($dados->senha)) {
        return 'Falta o campo senha';
    }

    $operador = [
        'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
        'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
        'ope_login'       => $dados->login,         
        //'ope_senha'       => $dados->senha,           
        'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
        'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
        'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
        'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
    ];

    $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Ou com empty que vai checar se é vazia:

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
{
    if (empty($dados->senha)) {
        return 'Falta o campo senha';
    }

    $operador = [
        'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
        'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
        'ope_login'       => $dados->login,         
        //'ope_senha'       => $dados->senha,           
        'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
        'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
        'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
        'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
    ];

    $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Poderia ser interessante usar [**Exceptions**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), assim por exemplo:

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
{
    if (empty($dados->senha)) {
        throw new Exception('Falta o campo senha');
    }

    $operador = [
        'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
        'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
        'ope_login'       => $dados->login,         
        //'ope_senha'       => $dados->senha,           
        'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
        'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
        'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
        'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
    ];

    $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

E no momento de usar:

```
try {
    $objeto->atualizar({
       ...  
    ));

    //... continua aqui se não falhar
} catch ($ee) {
    echo 'Erro: ',  $ee->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Se deseja adicionar o item basta usar assim:

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
{
    $operador = [
        'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
        'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
        'ope_login'       => $dados->login,              
        'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
        'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
        'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
        'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
    ];

    if (isset($dados->senha)) {   
        $operador['ope_senha'] = $dados->senha;
    }

    $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: Se $dados->senha NÃO existir, então o array $operador não deve conter o item $senha, caso contrário, o array $operador DEVE conter o item $senha

Comment: @WagnerFilho Você NÃO EXPLICOU isto na pergunta, de qualquer forma basta ajustar o IF criando um ELSE!

Comment: certo, eu só queria evitar de escrever o array duas vezes.

Comment: @WagnerFilho não é necessário escrever duas vezes. Estou editando a resposta... Pronto, resposta editada.

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode utilizar o `isset` dessa forma:

```
public function atualizar($where, $dados)
{
    print_r($dados);

    $operador = [
        'ope_nome'        => $dados->nome,
        'ope_cpf'         => $dados->cpf,
        'ope_login'       => $dados->login,
        //'ope_senha'       => $dados->senha,           
        'ope_ramal'       => $dados->ramal,
        'ope_pin'         => $dados->pin,
        'ope_reset_senha' => $dados->reset_senha,
        'ope_ativo'       => $dados->ativo,
    ];

    if(isset($dados->senha)) {
        $operador['ope_senha']  => $dados->senha,  
    }

    $this->db->update($this->tb_operador, $operador, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Dessa forma, caso `$dados->senha` exista, ele adicionará o índice "ope_senha" no array `$operador`